# Scala confused about mutability and Array/Lists

Tags: scala

Given a simple Matrix implementation

```
class Matrix(val matrix: Array[Array[Double]]) {
...
  def add(scalar:Double) { matrix.map(_.map( _ + scalar )) }
  def set(row:Int,col:Int,value:Double) { matrix(row)(col) = value }
...
}
```

To my understanding Mutability means I can't reassign matrix but I **can** set new values within it. As demonstrated by set() working.

The implementation of add right now is broken, but i'm stuck as to how to best implement it. I was hopeful about using transform

```
def add(scalar:Double) { matrix.transform(_.transform( _ + scalar )) }  
// type mismatch; found : ...WrappedArray[Double] required: Array[Double]
```

But I can't get it to compile yet. So is there a way to get above example to work?

And please feel free to hammer any flaws in my logic about list/array mutability :P

Comment: also, the question is, what are you trying to achieve? Immutable code, or mutable code, or just somehow-functioning code?

Comment: matrix should remain immutable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, you can't reassign to `matrix`, because it is a `val` (the reference is immutable). Instances of `Array` can be changed, because the interface of `Array` so allows, which makes it a mutable class.

So `matrix =` is not allowed. The call with `matrix.map` is valid, it creates a new array, leaving `matrix` untouched. It also changes the sub arrays inside `matrix`, because of the second `map`. Not what you want. Finally, the result is not assignable to `matrix`, because assignments to `matrix` are not allowed

`transform` is indeed the way to go. But the arrays you want to make changes in are the ones in `matrix` (the *lines*), not `matrix` itself, which should still contain the same (but changed) lines. The proper call is

```
matrix.foreach(_.transform(_ + scalar)
```

Yet, your version should have worked. `transform` returns the target of the call. The point is that you can chain calls, `a.transform(...).doSomethingElse().andAgain()` (which you do not need here). So your matrix.transform should have been a transform(identity) - with the side effect that this particular identity would change the content of the lines, and that would have been fine.

The problem is that transform is not really a method of Array (arrays are in the JVM and have no such method). It comes from an implicit conversion. There are two notable implicit conversions from Array, one to `ArrayOps`, another one to `WrappedArray` (details in the article [Fighting Bit Rot with Types](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2009/2338/pdf/09005.OderskyM.2338.pdf), towards the end). Method `transform` is in `WrappedArray`. Its return type has to be `WrappedArray`, because transform is defined well above in the type hierarchy, and forces the result to be `this`. Which means the not too interesting result of `transform` should not be used for arrays. So you must go with `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something with the return value of the `matrix.map(_.map( _ + scalar ))`. Create a new matrix based on this value and return it:

```
def add(scalar:Double) = { new Matrix(matrix.map(_.map( _ + scalar ))) }
```

You can't assign to `matrix` again, since this is a property of `val`(unability to assign a new value). 
The usage is then:

```
val matrix = new Matrix(Array(Array(1,2)))
val newMatrix = matrix.add(5)
```